# 'gensim.models.doc2vec' has no attribute 'LabeledSentence'

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sentiment-analysis, gensim

I am using gensim in python 3 as shown within image below

[image]

In line no 11 I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: You have to post the code in the question and not attach photos. Anyway if you want to write a good answer you need to provide also the versions of tools and libraries that are you using while getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a deprecated import:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1886

if you want to use LabeledSentenced you must import it from the deprecated section:

```
from gensim.models.deprecated.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
```

So you have to do this:

```
LabeledSentence = gensim.models.deprecated.doc2vec.LabeledSentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way:

```
from gensim.models.deprecated.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
```

or better use:

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
```